# How not to display value in a tooltip if it equals to 0

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

My expression for the tooltip looks like this:

```
Audits = CALCULATE(
                    SUM(CountByType[StatusCount]), CountByType[Description]="Audits"
                   ) 
                    & 
                    " (" & FORMAT( DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(CountByType[StatusCount]), CountByType[Description]="Audits"),SUM(CountByType[StatusCount])),"0%"
                        ) &"
                    )"
```

I am concatenating two numbers in order to  display the % out of total.

[image]

So my question, how can I not display those tooltips that have value 0.
For example `New Business`, `Policy To Broker` and `Service Request` should not be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are all explicit measures you've created, try writing them like this:

```
Audits =
    VAR AuditCount = CALCULATE(
                         SUM(CountByType[StatusCount]),
                         CountByType[Description]="Audits")
    RETURN IF(AuditCount = 0,
               BLANK(),
               AuditCount & " (" &
               FORMAT(DIVIDE(AuditCount,SUM(CountByType[StatusCount])),"0%") &
               ")")
```

Returning a blank should make those tooltip lines disappear.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!